# How to solve the following square root?

Tags: roots

I'd like to know how to solve the following square root:-

$\sqrt{4+4x}$

The result is: $2\sqrt{x+1}$

I did not understand where the $x+1$ come from.

Comment: As per the rules of indices, we can write $$\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} * \sqrt{b}$$ So, $$\sqrt{4(x + 1)} = \sqrt{4} * \sqrt{x + 1}$$ and you can do the rest.

Comment: $\sqrt{4+4x} = \sqrt{4(1 + x)} = \sqrt{4}\sqrt{1+x} = 2 \sqrt{1+x}$ since $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ whenever at least $a$ or $b$ is positive.

Comment: Is it so hard to see that $4+4x=4(1+x)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, we are not solving anything since there is no equal sign; we are only *simplifying*: $$\sqrt{4+4x}=\sqrt{4(x+1)}=\sqrt{4}\cdot\sqrt{x+1}=2\sqrt{x+1}$$

I used the property that $$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$$

Comment: Note that your calculation is also valid if $x<-1$, since for the property $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ it suffices that $a$ or $b$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

For positive $a$ and $b$, $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$.
$$\sqrt{4+4x}=\sqrt{4(x+1)}=\sqrt4\sqrt{x+1}=2\sqrt{x+1}$$